# Drop shadow not applying in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, box-shadow

I have an issue where my drop shadow shows in Firefox and Chrome, but not in MS Edge for some reason. I have cleared my cache and it just reproduces the same result and doesn't show in Microsoft Edge.

```
box-shaddow:  0px 4px 15px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.54)
-moz-box-shadow:  0px 4px 15px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.54)
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 4px 15px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.54)
border-collapse: separate
```

Comment: What does F12 tools say when you select the affected element?

Comment: Your lines are missing terminal semicolons and you misspelled the property.

Answer (score 2):

This works (you might have to play with the shadow to suit your preference):

```
filter: drop-shadow(0px 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2))
```

Comment: Chrome understands filter, so it needs to be placed on top of box-shadow. Edge, on the other hand, only understands filter, so box-shadow will be ignored. You need to do this because, as MikeMo says, the settings of the two are most likely going to be different.